# Setf weird expansion

Tags: elisp-macros, setf

Trying to understand what `setf` can do, I called

```
(macroexpand '(setf (aref vec i) val))
⇒ (let* ((v vec) (v i)) (aset v v val))
```

This seems obviously wrong.

However I couldn't create an actual instance where `(setf (aref ..` fails. E.g.

```
 (setq vec (make-vector 10 nil) i 3 val 'foo)
 ⇒ foo
 (setf (aref vec i) val)
 ⇒ foo
 vec
 ⇒ [nil nil nil foo nil nil nil nil nil nil]
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: OK. I understand now. The two `v` symbols are not the same and `(let* ((form (macroexpand '(setf (aref vec i) val))) (symb1 (caar (cadr form))) (symb2 (caar (cdadr form)))) (equal symb1 symb2))` returns `nil`.

Comment: Strangely, the code for `setf` in source file `gv.el` seems to create the `v` symbols with a vanilla use of `(gensym "v")` and this should append a counter value after the "v" prefix, creating uninterned symbols `v0`, `v1`, `v2`, etc.

Comment: You might like to play with `print-gensym` to better see what's going on.

Comment: @stefan: I have emacs-26.1 and it has no `print-gensym` AFAICT :-( Does anyone have an explanation why the `(gensym "v")` in source file `gv.el` does not append `gensym-counter` ?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do have `print-gensym`, you likely just looked at the wrong place (try `C-h o` instead of `C-h f`).  The `let*` in your expanded code is likely generated by `macroexp-let2` which uses `make-symbol` rather than `gensym`.

Comment: @stefan. Oh ... I stupidly assumed that `print-gensym` was a function's name. (It sounds like one, no?) 1.0E99 thanks for the tips, I'm always happy to learn more about emacs. And I must say I was quite dumbfounded when I first saw the weird expansion. I feel better now that I understand why it was a false alarm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your comment you've figured this out for yourself, but...

In the macro expansion you're seeing the *printed representation* of two independent symbols with the same name.  Most likely both of those symbols are uninterned.

A printed representation like this, if passed back to the lisp reader, would *not* be equivalent to the original, as the lisp reader would intern the symbols.

This is similar to:

```
(list (make-symbol "v") (make-symbol "v"))
(v v)
```

Comment: Worth noting that setting `print-gensym` and `print-circle` to `t` produces a printed representation which can read back to something equivalent.